# trying to run a function asynchronously using Async/Await, not working c#?

Tags: c#, async-await

I want to run a method asynchronously from my web api code but I am not getting the desired behavior.

I am trying to do the LongCallMethod in an asynchronous way. So that I am able to return success to my user before the LongCallMethod completes.

I have tried various combination of calls with await and async but not getting any success still. 
I might not be understanding the concept of async/await correctly.

Can you please let me know what's the mistake I am making?

My controller code is below

```
 [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        PracticeAsync p = new PracticeAsync();
        p.LongCallMethod();
        return "Success";
    }
```

The code for the class PracticeAsync is below:

```
 public class PracticeAsync
{
    public async Task LongCallMethod()
    {
        var x = await CallThis();
    }

    public async Task<dynamic> CallThis()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000); //DB call
        return "done";
    }
}
```

Comment: replace Thread.Sleep with await Task.Delay

Comment: Why do you call `p.LongCallMethod()` when your async method is `CallMethod`?

Comment: I am getting the desired behavior using Task.Delay. Thanks @MistyK

Comment: as for the explanation: `Thread.Sleep` is a blocking call, even putting in some `async` and `await` keywords are not going to change that. `Task.Delay` is the non-blocking variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to do the LongCallMethod in an asynchronous way. So that I am able to return success to my user before the LongCallMethod completes.

[That's not how `async` works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx).

You'll need to use SignalR or a [proper distributed architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/architecture-styles/web-queue-worker). Specifically, your webapp should place its work into a reliable queue, and have an independent service read from that queue and do the work. ASP.NET was designed to serve web requests, and has severe reliability limitations if you try to force it to do otherwise.